# sqlite3 querySingle() unrecognized token ":"

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Trying to run a query and I keep getting the error response, I've tried several methods, including the same example from PHP.net with a mockup DB. x.x what is wrong with WAMPs SQLite3?

> Warning: SQLite3::querySingle(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, unrecognized token: ":"

```
    function linkexists( $link ) {
        $this->varr = $this->querySingle( 'SELECT link FROM link_hits WHERE link=' . $this->escapeString( $link ) );
        return ( isset( $this->varr ) ) ? true : false; 
    }
```

Comment: so, what is $link? - Most likely it is not properly escaped data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem `$link` cannot be embedded directly into the query because contains characters that cause the query to be misinterpreted.

The variable should be properly escaped before inserting into the query and enclosed between double (or single) quotes

```
$this->varr = $this->querySingle('SELECT link FROM link_hits WHERE link="' . $this->escapeString( $link ) . '"' );
```

See for reference

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.escapestring.php

Comment: So it seems url_encode() doesn't help in this case. I was trying to preplan for this.

Comment: Yes, you have to enclose the string between quotes is the query. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ohhh well that's basic. Duhh. Thank you! Meh every time I come back to scripting.